# i couldn't get the download URL for the image

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Get The download url and assign it to a variable

```
<html>
<head>
    <h1>retrieve data</h1>
    <h2 id=myimg></h2>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            //firebase initialization
        };

      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    <script>
        storageRef.child('1.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function (event) {
                var blob = xhr.response;
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.send();


            var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
            img.src = url;
        }).catch(function (error) {

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i want the download url to be assigned 
**i want to retrieve the download URL from the firestorage and assign it to a variable**
[image]

what modification should i do in this code to get the download URL of the uploaded image

Comment: I think you need a relative path of the image. Try `pics/1.jpg` because it seems you have a folder called `pics`.

Comment: Also, the first part until `xhr.send()` is for downloading the image. Remove that section if all you want to do is assign it to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the folder you're getting the image from `'pics/1.jpg'` then remove the first section of your code that downloads the image and leave the bottom part that only assigns the URL to the image.

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
storageRef.child('pics/1.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {

    var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
    img.src = url;

}).catch(function (error) {

});
```

Comment: the console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: storageRef is not defined"

Comment: I've added the declaration for you